# Abstract Algebra: Ring Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $d=\text{gcd}(m,n)$, where $d>1$. Define $\tau: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z_m} \oplus \mathbb{Z_n}$ by $\tau(x) = ([x]_m,[x]_n)$. Consider, $([m/d]_m,[n/d]_n) \in \mathbb{Z_m} \oplus \mathbb{Z_n}$.

> Claim: There is no $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\tau(x) =([m/d]_m,[n/d]_n)$.

$\bullet$ By definition $\tau(x) = ([m/d]_m,[n/d]_n) \iff [x]_m=[m/d]_n $ and $[x]_n=[n/d]_n$, which is the case $\iff x = m/d = mk$ and $x=n/d +nj$. I came about this element in a few ($6$ or $7$) examples and figured maybe it was always true, but I can't seem to move past what I've presented. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion does not appear to be true, Let $m=n=2$. Then $m/d=n/d=1$. But by the definition of $\tau$, we have $\tau(1)=([1]_m,[1]_n)$.

Edit: For a somewhat less trivial example, let $m=6$ and $n=10$. Then $m/d=3$ and $n/d=5$. Note that $\tau(15)=([3]_m,[5]_n)$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll try a different approach to this problem. I was considering $m \not = n$.

Comment: I added an example with $m\ne n$.